# How can I install fedora to an existing partition?

Tags: fedora

During the install I've selected "Custom" Storage Configuration. Under Unknown partitions I select the one I want (it's already ext4) and enter `/` for its Mount Point, but it keeps just getting reset. How do I select it as being the root partition?

Comment: After 5 years, there is only one answer and it a) does not work for me and b) has not been accepted or graded.  I really want to do this, but the machine I'm on has a lot of existing OS installations (about 21 partitions), and I don't want to break anything.  I can't get to where the selected root is the partition I want to use.  It insists on picking some of my free space to create a new partition 22.  Not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently root partitions need to be re-formatted, or the installer won't accept it.

[image]

After setting up the partitions, use the "Done" button hidden in the top left.