# Install Fedora Xfce 37 to existing (empty) partition

Tags: partitioning, installation, fedora, xfce4

I have Fedora Xfce 37 installation .iso on a ventoy thumb drive.  I want to install it on my M.2 drive in partition 6, which is currently formatted ext4.  I get just so far: after I've selected custom install and set to reformat, it really wants to create a new partition (number 22) and won't let me select partition 6 for the purpose.  It does not help for me to use gparted to clear the partition -- in this case I cannot get the installer to stop trying to claim the whole drive and presumably erase the partitions I already have.  I've also tried to let it set up partitions automatically and then modify: I still can't get it to use the partition 6 space for root.

Since 256 GB is clearly enough space, is there some way to get Fedora to sandwich itself into this space?  The only previous question that seemed close was [6 years old with no votes](https://superuser.com/questions/1230009/how-can-i-install-fedora-to-an-existing-partition) and just one answer (that did not work for me - I did not get the same response from the installer.)

Comment: Can you at least link the previous question & tell us what 'did not work', so we're not starting from ground zero.

Comment: @Tetsujin I edited the question.

Comment: In the end I took a different path.  I figured out what the installer was doing, deleted some partitions I didn't need, including all other Linux remnants and Installed Fedora alongside Windows.  Not a lot of fun with that installer.  I'm sure it's fine once you know it but the documentation is not friendly to newbs.  I did learn enough so that I could answer the question now, but it would take me a day or so to be sure I got it right, and I have other things on my dance card.

Comment: [Fedora 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux_release_history#Fedora_Linux_36) (with [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)).